# Is there a way to create and release azure release pipeline using only az pipelines cli?

Tags: azure-devops, command-line-interface, azure-pipelines, az

I'm trying to automate azure build & release pipeline by using az devops extension cli. I was able to create and run build pipelines. But unable to create release pipelines by only using the cli.

Microsoft docs is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to create and release azure release pipeline using only az pipelines cli?

I am afraid we could create the azure release pipeline using only az pipelines cli but could not release it.

As the document [az pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest), we could to create the azure release pipeline by the command line:

```
az pipelines release create
```

Check the [az pipelines release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/release?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-pipelines-release-create) for some more details info.

But we could not release the azure release pipeline using only az pipelines cli, since there is no such command line to use. And the [az pipelines runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/runs?view=azure-cli-latest) still not work for release.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a release from a pipeline but not a pipeline.

```
az pipelines release create --definition-name=MyPipeline
```

This will create a release from your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, The release is trigger and the deployment is not done using this **az pipelines release create --definition-name=MyPipeline** azure cli comments.

[image]